# What is the usage of DEBUG_NEW and __FILE__?

Tags: c++

I saw the follow macros,

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#UNDEF THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif
```

What is the usage of above macro?

Thank you

Comment: Is this still relevant when compiling with e.g. VS2017? I've got this in my old code and wondering if it can be removed.

Answer (score 13):

DEBUG_NEW is just a MACRO which is usually defined as:

```
#define DEBUG_NEW new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW
```

So that wherever you use `new`, it also can keep track of the file and line number which could be used to locate memory leak in your program.

And `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` are [predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which evaluate to the filename and line number respectively where you use them!

Read the following article which explains the technique of using DEBUG_NEW with other interesting macros, very beautifully:

[A Cross-Platform Memory Leak Detector](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm)

---

From [Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_new),

> Debug_new refers to a technique in C++
>   to overload and/or redefine operator
>   new and operator delete in order to
>   intercept the memory allocation and
>   deallocation calls, and thus debug a
>   program for memory usage. **It often
>   involves defining a macro named
>   DEBUG_NEW, and makes new become
>   something like new(_*FILE*_, _*LINE*_)
>   to record the file/line information on
>   allocation.** Microsoft Visual C++ uses
>   this technique in its Microsoft
>   Foundation Classes. There are some
>   ways to extend this method to avoid
>   using macro redefinition while still
>   able to display the file/line
>   information on some platforms. There
>   are many inherent limitations to this
>   method. It applies only to C++, and
>   cannot catch memory leaks by C
>   functions like malloc. However, it can
>   be very simple to use and also very
>   fast, when compared to some more
>   complete memory debugger solutions.

Answer (score 1):

`_DEBUG` is an arbitrarily named, but often chosen, command line symbol which indicates that extra code and support for debugging the program should be compiled in.  Often this causes extra checks to help isolate programming flaws, or causes extra messages to be output for the benefit of the developer.

`DEBUG_NEW` isn't clear, but it is probably an alias for `new()` which does extra validation associated with `new()` and `delete()`.

`__FILE__` is a built-in preprocessor symbol which evaluates to the filename of the module being compiled.  For example "MyProgram.cc".

Answer (score 0):

One common usage of `__FILE__` is in designing error-logging functions.  You can use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` together to report the exact source code location where the error occurred.

I have designed exception libraries and `assert()`-type functions that log this information.  One such use is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026649/getting-information-about-where-c-exceptions-are-thrown-inside-of-catch-block/3026819#3026819).

EDIT: Another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790515/advantage-of-macro-over-in-line-in-c/4790610#4790610)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually use it, I would advice you to remove that code, because it comflicts with other ligitimate overloads of operator new.

See the discussion here:

[Is there a way to automatically have a #define reproduced in each source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326656/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-have-a-define-reproduced-in-each-source-file/1326779#1326779)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this combination of makroses and preprocessor commands, is used in MFC projets, to track memory-leaks. It has to be included into you source file, and literraly means following:

Everything between `#ifdef _DEBUG` and `#endif` executed only in DEBUG mode of your compiler.

The string: `#define new DEBUG_NEW`, means that whenever you use operater new in your code, it will be replaced by macro `DEBUG_NEW`. And then, when you do an object dump, `DEBUG_NEW` will allow you to pinpoint the sources of memory leaks.

The strings: `#UNDEF THIS_FILE` and `static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;` - redefine the meaning of `THIS_FILE` and remembers the current file-name and line number.