# Overloaded operator new in the presence of DEBUG_NEW macro

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

In an MFC project I'm using an external library [TTL](https://github.com/SINTEF-Geometry/TTL) that [overloads](https://github.com/SINTEF-Geometry/TTL/blob/master/src/utils/HandleId.cpp) `operator new`. My problem is that I have a memory leak and I'd like to make use of the diagnostics given by [`DEBUG_NEW`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421754/what-is-the-usage-of-debug-new-and-file). However I'm only able to compile this with `DEBUG_NEW` commented-out else I get the error below.

The following demonstrates it. It is an MCVE when the Visual Studio project is made as a console application **with MFC headers**.

```
// The problem is when this is uncommented
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

struct HandleId
{
  HandleId() {}

  void* operator new (size_t t) {
    return HandleId::operator new(t, 0, 0, 0);
  };
  void* operator new (size_t t, int, const char* file, int line) {
    HandleId* tmp = (HandleId*)calloc(1, t);
    return tmp;
  };
  void operator delete (void* v) {
    free(v);
  }
};

namespace hed
{
  struct Node : public virtual HandleId
  {
    Node() {};
    Node(double x, double y, double z = 0.0) {}
  };
}

struct DtmNode : public hed::Node
{
  DtmNode() {};
  DtmNode(short pntRef, double x, double y, double z)
    : hed::Node(x, y, z)
  {};
};

int main()
{
  DtmNode* pNode = new DtmNode(0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
  return 0;
}
```

With `DEBUG_NEW` uncommented the above compilation fails (VS2019) with.

> error C2661: `HandleId::operator new`: no overloaded function takes 3 arguments

Up to now I've lived with the macro commented-out. But I now *do* want it in debug builds for the obvious reason of helping catch memory leaks during debugging. `DtmNode` is my class which I can change. `HandleId` and the `hed` namespace belong to the library.

My question:

1. Is there a way to compile this with `DEBUG_NEW` uncommented?
2. Alternatively, is there any way to tell `DtmNode` not to use the overloaded `operator new` when in _DEBUG mode so that the `DEBUG_NEW` is used as per "normal"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be reasonable to replace `DtmNode* pNode` with something, that won't leak? Like a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is 'no'.

You can make this sort of thing compile by selectively undefining new using #pragma push_macro/pop_macro:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
...
int main()
{
#pragma push_macro("new")
#undef new
  DtmNode* pNode = new DtmNode(0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
#pragma pop_macro("new");

  return 0;
}
```

It won't allow you to track objects from the library using MFC's debug allocator (you would have to completely replace the library's allocator for that). But it will at least allow your program to work in the presence of a non-matching operator new.

Comment: Keep in mind that defining a macro with the same name as a keyword (`new`) results in undefined behavior.

Comment: It might be undefined but visual c++ (which the presence of MFC overwhelmingly indicates use of) behaves reasonably in this circumstance.

Comment: Yes, the **implementation and use** of **MFC** works when that macro is defined. It may well be that your code will mostly work when you define a similar macro, if you are careful to only use that macro in the same way that it's used in MFC, and to **always** use it in exactly the same way as it's used in MFC. It was a bad idea in MFC, and it's a bad idea in any other code.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir in your answer, doesn't it make more sense to use the pragmas around the declaration of `struct HandleId` where the `new` keyword in the operator declarations must not be remapped, rather than in the body of `main` where a remapped `new` is OK and intended to be used?

Comment: Accepting this on the basis of your first sentence. In the end I found the memory leak without the MFC assistance.